# Need some suggestions on how to print a histogram more neatly

Tags: c, io

I'm writing a program that will read input and then give back a histogram of the character count from K & R - Ex. 1.13

Any suggestions on how I can improve my code? Does it matter whether or not if I test for status in condition or out first?  I have noticed in my examples people test to see if c is a blank or tab first.

I think I need to revisit my histogram. It doesn't really scale the results. It just draws a hyphen based on the length.

*Revised to make a little bit more readable I think.*

```
// Print a histogram of the length of words in it's input.

#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 2
#define MAX 99

int main(){

    int c;  // the character
    int countOfLetters = 0;
    int insideWord = OUT;
    int frequencyOfLengths[MAX];
    int longestWordCount = 0;
    int i, j; // Counters

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        frequencyOfLengths[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
            if (insideWord == IN){
                if (countOfLetters > MAX){
                    return 1;
                }
                ++frequencyOfLengths[countOfLetters];
                if (countOfLetters >= longestWordCount) longestWordCount = countOfLetters;
            }
            countOfLetters = 0;
        }
        else {
            countOfLetters++;
            insideWord = IN;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= longestWordCount; i++){
        printf("%3i : %3i     ", i, frequencyOfLengths[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < frequencyOfLengths[i]; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` mean? I can't compile that but it's tagged `C`.

Comment: You don't check whether a word length is smaller than `MAXWORD` before accessing `charCount`, which you should.

Comment: *"how I can improve my code?"* When I got rid of all the `_t` palaver and replaced `#include "stdafx.h"` with `#include <stdio.h>` it compiled, but when I run it it doesn't do anything. Should there be some kind of a prompt to tell me what is expected?

Comment: oh sorry about that, i was using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely scale results, check out my [Character Histogram](https://github.com/rvonsch/reading-kernighan-ritchie-c) that does a horizontal scaling histogram.

Also, you could benefit a y-axis label. It's hard to tell which bar is for which kind of word length. I have no idea which bar is for what word length.

I added this code right before you display the histogram, it basically halves every value, which does throw off your bar number labels. You can figure it out!

```
// Iterates and tells us the most frequent word length
int mostFrequent = 0;
for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; i++)
    if (charCount[i] > mostFrequent)
        mostFrequent = charCount[i];

// If the bar will be too big, cut every value in half
while (mostFrequent > 60) {
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; i++)
        if (charCount[i] > 0) {
            charCount[i] /= 2;
            charCount[i] |= 1;
        }

    // Check again to find the most frequent word length category
    mostFrequent = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; i++)
        if (charCount[i] > mostFrequent)
            mostFrequent = charCount[i];
}
```

Honestly the bars are hard to read, maybe just use a single row of characters such as █ !

Great book so far, we're practically reading it together and are on the same page!

Cheers

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.  If the bar is too big, what if the the lenght of your freqencies is 1?